# Angular is not sending objects in objects

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm sending this JSON with Angular.js to my node.js/express.js service:

```
{
  "name": "MyGuitar",
  "type": "electric",
  "userid": "123",
  "likes": 0,
  "dislike": 0,
  "guitarParts": {
"body": {
  "material": "/content/img/hout.jpg",
  "_id": "5566d6af274e63cf4f790858",
  "color": "#921d1d"
},
"head": {

},
"neck": {
  "material": "/content/img/hout.jpg",
  "_id": "556d9beed90b983527c684be",
  "color": "#46921d"
},
"frets": {

},
"pickup": {

},
"bridge": {

},
"buttons": {

}
```

}
 }

The guitarParts are not saved in the MongoDB database.
Mongoose inserts the following:

Mongoose: guitars.insert({ name: 'MyGuitar', type: 'electric', userid: '123', likes: 0, _id: ObjectId("557023af9b321b541d4d416e"), guitarParts: [], __v: 0})

This is my Mongoose model:

```
   guitarPart = new Schema({  
   id: { type: String, required: true },  
   color: { type: String, required: true },  
   material: { type: String, required: true },  
   x: { type: Number, required: false },  
   y: { type: Number, required: false },  
   width: { type: Number, required: false },  
   height: { type: Number, required: false},  
});  

guitarParts = new Schema({  
    body: [guitarPart],  
    neck: [guitarPart],  
    head: [guitarPart],  
    bridge: [guitarPart],  
    frets: [guitarPart],  
    pickup: [guitarPart],  
    buttons: [guitarPart]  
});  

guitar = new Schema({  
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },  
    type: { type: String, required: true },  
    userid: { type: String },  
    likes: { type: Number },  
    dislikes: { type: Number },  
    guitarParts: [guitarParts],  
    kidsguitar: { type: Boolean },  
    lefthanded: { type: Boolean },  
    assemblykit: { type: Boolean }  
},  
{   
    collection: 'guitars'   
});
```

I don't know what's going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Typo `guitarparts` -> `guitarParts`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the mongoose documentation of Subdocuments says: *Sub-documents are docs with schemas of their own which are elements of a **parents document array***

And in your schema you provided: guitarParts is not an array, it is an object and a guitarPart is not array it is an object too. So that's why it is not saving.

So the correct way to model your Schema it would be:

```
var guitarDefinition = {
  _id: {type: String, required: true},
  color: {type: String, required: true},
  material: {type: String, required: true},
  x: Number,
  y: Number,
  width: Number,
  heigth: Number
};

var guitarSchema = Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },  
  type: { type: String, required: true },  
  userid: String,  
  likes: Number,  
  dislikes: Number ,  
  kidsguitar: Boolean,  
  lefthanded: Boolean ,  
  assemblykit: Boolean,

  guitarParts: {
    body: guitarDefinition,  
    neck: guitarDefinition,  
    head: guitarDefinition,  
    bridge: guitarDefinition,  
    frets: guitarDefinition,  
    pickup: guitarDefinition,  
    buttons: guitarDefinition 
  }
});
```

Actually I have run in my computer and it is saving you can see my complete code here: https://gist.github.com/wilsonbalderrama/f10c38f9fb510865edc2